# Windows DNS server addresses and firewall settings are keep getting reset

Tags: windows, ethernet, windows-firewall

I'm running Windows 10 and my network connection setting is getting reset once a while.

I'm basically having the exact same problem as [this post](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/605828-dns-server-resetting-and-windows-firewall-turning-back-on/)

I manually enter my IP address, subnet mask, default gateway and preferred DNS server as well as alternate DNS server. 
I then add some of the windows applications to the windows firewall so that they can have a network access.

The problem is, once in a while (can't seem to find a reason for such change) (about once in two weeks? or month?), the DNS server addresses would reset and empty the address fields.
Also, firewall settings are reset so that I can't even remote access my PC.

At first, I thought it was a malware, but my PC is doing that again even after I formatted it and installed anti-virus software. (I'm using [AhnLab V3](http://global.ahnlab.com/site/main.do) ).

Could anyone tell me possible causes of such DNS and firewall reset?

p.s. My LAN card on device manager shows 'Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller'. Could it possibly be a device driver problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I started having the same problem with my computer after I upgraded to Windows 10. (I have the same Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller as well). I have been using the same computer with Windows 8.1 without any problem; so it is either an issue with Windows 10 or the updated device drivers used with Window 10.